# Creating multiple IBM Watson services

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

So far, I have attached 3 scripts to my character, one for TtS, one for StT, and one for ToneAnalysis, and I am learning how to also integrate Assistant(Conversation) and more...

Each script contains at least one `Runnable.Run( CreateService() )` that uses an `IEnumerator` to verify credentials and instantiate service.

Should I place all the code from these scripts (and future services that I add) in one script, or is it OK that all these credential-verifications and service-instantiations are occurring simultaneously?

Comment: should this go in the [game development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com) forum?

Comment: @i.do.stuff It could go there, but I have seen more related tags here; e.g. ibm-watson, watson-conversation, etc... I will also post it there if I don't get any answers here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have code that instantiates services running simultaneously without problems. IBM Cloud and Watson APIs have rate limitation which means that if you send a high volume of API calls in a short period, the API will return a `429 Rate Limitation error`.

Speech to Text, Text to Speech and Tone, Watson Assistant and Tone Analyzer have a high rate, so most applications(like yours) never hit the rate limitation. Each service has a documentation page describing the limits. For example [Watson Assistant Rate limitation](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant#rate-limiting).

Comment: Thank you. I came across a few massive classes like [this](https://github.com/YnotZer0/unity3d_watsonSdk/blob/master/Watson_newServices.cs) so I thought perhaps it is a must to stick all the service-creation calls in one method.

Comment: It seems like I cannot access another service that is created and instantiated in another script! In my `ExampleAssistant` script, I make a call to my `TTS` script (`_ttsContent = output; _watsonTTS_script.CallTTS(_ttsContent);`) but I get a `Null Reference` error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Check how you are passing variables between the classes. I would define a class with all the services call it `Watson` and then have a reference to that class from all the places you want to use the services.